# Is it possible for an assigned entry (via field type Entries field) to know what it has been assigned to?

Tags: entries, structure, fieldtypes, parents

I have two entry types **'pipeline'** (structure) and **'series'** (channel). I know I can add children in a structure, but I want to keep 'pipeline' and 'series' separate to avoid duplication, as a series can belong to multiple pipelines.

I assign a series to a pipeline with a field type Entries field.

As an example I assign 'series1' to 'pipeline1' and 'pipeline2'.

What I'd like to know:

a) Is it possible for 'series1' to know it is assigned to 'pipeline1' and 'pipeline2'?

b) If it's not possible, is there a way to update the series entry when assigning to a pipeline?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `relatedTo` param ([docs](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/element-queries/entry-queries.html#relatedto)).

```
{% set relatedPipelines = craft.entries()
    .section('pipeline')
    .relatedTo(yourSeriesEntry)
    .all() %}
```

Would return pipelines (if any) related to your *series1*.

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly!